# Regex matching first word and any word

Tags: regex, grep

I have a log file with a list of many entries. With grep regex I want to match the first word and another word which can be anywhere in the string.

For example, if I specified "user1" the search would search:

`grep -E '^(IP_CONNECT|IP_DISCONNECT) user1' file.txt`

However this won't match unless user1 is at the beginning of the string whereas I want to match it if it appears anywhere in the string. How is this done?

Comment: `^(IP_CONNECT|IP_DISCONNECT) user1` means "start of line followed by IP_CONNECT or IP_DISCONNECT, then a single space, then user1".  Is this really what you want to match on?

Comment: No I want to match "start of line followed by IP_CONNECT or IP_DISCONNECT and somewhere in that line user1 must be present"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want to match lines that begin with either "IP_CONNECT" or "IP_DISCONNECT", followed by one or more of [most] any characters, followed by "user1".

```
grep -E '^(IP_CONNECT|IP_DISCONNECT).+user1' file.txt
```

You also might find tools like [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) helpful in exploring this.

Comment: Thanks! A side question: Is this fairly inefficient for huge files? Would there possibly be a more efficient command/method such as knowing how many spaces before the match?

Comment: Inefficient in which ways? I can't say that I've benched marked "less  specific" vs "more specific" regexes to provide a useful answer.

Comment: Hm why doesn't it match PLAYER_RENAMED in this: http://regexr.com/39f8n

Comment: None of the "PLAYER_RENAMED" lines _also_ contain "duke" so what did you expect it to match on?